# Tutorial: Server Broadcast with SignalR 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I read this excellent tutorial : http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr.

I then downloaded the NuGet example package `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Sample 2.2.0` (https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.sample), and then I  created new asp.net mvc 5 project with vs 2015 with an index page.

I assume that `app.MapSignalR()` is called in the `Startup.Configuration` method.

Like lots of people I got the error: `ticker.client is undefined.`

The real problem is the `var ticker = $.connection.stockTicker`, is always null because  `$.connection` has no `stockTicker` property defined - because the hub can't instantiate it.

Does anybody know the reason for this error?

The orignial tutorial is http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr I hosted my sample project zip to my open onedrive : https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=11357B31E08CCFEE&resid=11357B31E08CCFEE%21107&authkey=ALMOtmTFdCdsyV8

The "SignalR.Sample" directory content in the solution is the basic Template to integrate in asp.net mvc 4/5/6 project. So I integrate it in Views/Home/Index.cshtml page. Js refernces are in file Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml .

Exact problem is var ticker = $.connection.stockTicker is null (no initialize connection done with the server).

If you can help me, i thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you added the `jQuery` and `Stockticker` scripts in your _Layout, but you didn't add the signalr/hubs. The scripts must be loaded in this exact order:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/SignalR.StockTicker.js"></script>
```

Reference:
 [ASP.NET SignalR Hubs API Guide - JavaScript Client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#clientsetup)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the JavaScript file references in StockTicker.html are correct. That is, make sure that the jQuery version in your script tag (1.10.2 in the example) is the same as the jQuery version in your project's Scripts folder, and make sure that the SignalR version in your script tag is the same as the SignalR version in your project's Scripts folder. Change the file names in the script tags if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Any CPU as your active solution platform. I switched it to x64 and that made it so SignalR could not load since it had an incorrect platform.